# F#: Is the Condition attribute not supported in some (or all) tags in .fsproj files?

Tags: visual-studio, configuration, msbuild, f#, conditional-statements

For an F# project with dual platforms "Xbox 360" and "x86," I have the following in my project file:

```
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'Xbox 360'">
    <Reference Include="Arands.ContentTracker.Xbox">
     <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\_Libs\XNA\ContentTracker\ContentTracker\bin\Xbox 360\Release\Arands.ContentTracker.Xbox.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'x86'">
    <Reference Include="Arands.ContentTracker">
    <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\_Libs\XNA\ContentTracker\ContentTracker\bin\x86\Release\Arands.ContentTracker.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

For some reason, neither Arands.ContentTracker.dll nor Arands.ContentTracker.Xbox.dll are added as references in my project, regardless of which platform I select (Xbox 360 or x86).

The result is the same with the following:

```
<Reference Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'Xbox 360'" Include="Arands.ContentTracker.Xbox">
    <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\_Libs\XNA\ContentTracker\ContentTracker\bin\Xbox 360\Release\Arands.ContentTracker.Xbox.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'x86'" Include="Arands.ContentTracker">
    <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\_Libs\XNA\ContentTracker\ContentTracker\bin\x86\Release\Arands.ContentTracker.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Is the `Condition` attribute simply ignored in .fsproj files?

Splitting a project in two sucks.  I want the current chosen platform to determine the current configuration and what goes on in a build, not (for example) which project tree I had expanded when I double-clicked a .fs code file in the Solution Explorer.  Having multiple projects just to accommodate different platforms has caused me some fairly significant headaches, and even confuses Intellisense (e.g. not identifying `System.Collections.Generic.HashSet` as unavailable when my platform is set to Xbox 360).

UPDATE: I've managed to get it working.  My mistake was expecting the Solution Explorer to reflect a change in configuration, e.g. for the References in the F# project to actually show the relevant references, as I'm used to seeing for C# projects with conditional tags.  Apparently, F# projects simply display nothing in the References section when there are conditionals involved (unfortunately).

Once I got past the assumption that the Solution Explorer would accurately reflect the relevant assets after a platform change, I was able to focus on other areas of the solution (namely, the Configuration Manager and References to the F# project in the C# projects) that required more attention.

Thanks for your assistance, all!  I'd prefer to award the points to Preet Sangha, since it was his question that provided the insight that allowed me to get past the aforementioned assumption.

Comment: Question is: Do both project configs build from the command line? IOW Are you experiencing a VS/MSBUILD/FSPROJ issue rather than a pure MSBUILD/FSPROJ one?

Comment: If I split the .fsproj into two projects, yes, they both build.  (If that's what you're asking.)

Comment: FWIW we've been using conditional references in FSharpx and it works just fine, e.g. https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpx/blob/master/src/FSharpx.Core/FSharpx.Core.fsproj#L77

Comment: @MiloDC - No I'm asking if both configurations build from the command line with the conditionals in place, within a single project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should just be an MSBuild thing, and should work... it may be useful to run `msbuild -v:diag ...` to diagnose what's going wrong; perhaps things are in the project file in the wrong order?